# Rails: Hide Paramater in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In order to reply to a message received from User A, I am passing in User A's `id` through the link_to tag:

```
<%= link_to "Reply", new_message_path(:id => @user.id), class: "button" %>
```

I can then make sure that the recipient is @user. But the issue is that when the new view opens with the send message form, the URL also has User A's id. How can I hide that? Because someone can easily change the parameter and the message can then be sent to another User instead of User A.

Comment: you can use a custom permalink, you can do so via the “Permalink”, user have a custom permalink, permalink can generate md5 or other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the id, you need to send the parameter somehow. You can't and probably don't want to hide it.

If someone changes the url to send the message to another user, he does so willingly.

If you want to make sure a user can only send messages to certain users, you should do so by setting up permissions.

Hiding the parameter won't gain you anything.

Comment: Okay, I did implement a before_filter so that the User can only send messages to certain users and it does solve my problem. I was just wondering if I could hide the parameter for additional security. Not that it matters I guess. Thanks.

Comment: You could like @Benjamin Sinclaire mentioned, use a post method, but I wouldn't bother with it. It won't give any additional security, but it would stop the parameter from being shown in the url.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

I mean you could hide it and use a POST method and an hidden field for the id, but the risk would be the same: anybody could change the id.

You need to ask yourself the question "how to secure my message system so users cannot send messages to other users". I would suggest to create a token field in your message (like a long random string) and use this token to verify that the message is sent to the correct user. It require a bit of coding, but is your application needs security you can't avoid it

Answer (score 0):

With this syntax you still have this trouble?

```
<%= link_to "Reply", new_message_path(@user), class: "button" %>
```

What code in your controller action 'create' ?